# Reactive Location - Handle success and failure block

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager, reactive-swift

It might be simple question.
I'm using [Reactive Location](https://github.com/AckeeCZ/ReactiveLocation), to get user's current location, please find my below code,

```
    ReactiveLocation.authorizeAction.apply(.whenInUse).startWithResult {
        switch $0 {
        case let .success(status):
            print("Current user permission status on WhenInUse is \(status)")
        case let .failure(error):                
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Here error is **.restricted** and **.denied**, I want user to be presented with the error message according to error. How to identify it.

In above code, completion block looks like this,

[image]

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking "how to check if `.restricted` or `.denied`"?

Comment: @ABeard89 yes exactly

Comment: @ABeard89 above library is using [Result github](https://github.com/antitypical/Result)

Comment: Then, you do that the same way you checked for `.success` and `.failure`. Use a `switch`.

Comment: it is not working, please try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest learning more about Swift `enum`.

You can check for `.restricted` and `.denied` the same way you checked for `.success` and `.failure`.

The only difference is `LocationAuthorizationError` doesn't have associated values.

```
ReactiveLocation.authorizeAction.apply(.whenInUse).startWithResult {
    switch $0 {
    case let .success(status):
        print("Current user permission status on WhenInUse is \(status)")

    case let .failure(actionError):
        switch actionError {
        case .producerFailed(.restricted):
            print("Authorization Restricted")
        case .producerFailed(.denied):
            print("Authorization Denied")
        default:
            break
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to? It's an enumeration. Doesn't get any simpler.

Comment: then check once dear, I got it, it should be  case .producerFailed(.denied):

Comment: and thank you for your answer and more I know about swift enumeration

Comment: Updated answer to use the `ActionError` enum defined by `ReactiveSwift`.